# nodejs with leaflet memory leak when using a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, leaflet

i am getting a memory leak in the browser/client once I insert a function into the client.js:

```
socket.on("botnet", function(t) {
var e = JSON.parse(t);
...
$(e).on('click', function (e) {
     console.log(id);
});
});
```

Once I remove (any) the function there is no memory leak. What I am missing? Why is the memory leak happening in the first place?

Comment: `e` is a query string? why do you json parse it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible that because you are creating a click event for every time the botnet event is triggered. I would instead use a scope with the `.on` function and remove the handler from inside of it to the outside scope.

Do: `.on("click","div",function(){});`

Instead of: `.on("click",function(){});`

and remove it outside of the socket event like so:

```
socket.on("botnet", function(t) {
    var e = JSON.parse(t);
});
$(expectedClassOrID).on('click','div', function (e) {
    console.log(id);
});
```

Comment: that is certainly good feedback. when i move it outside the botnet event i have trouble accessing the leaflet elements by id however. trying further

Comment: You can change the scope yet again to the parent container. like so: `$container.on("click",expectedClassOrID)`